# Busca com Ruby on Rails, para gerar um relatorio

Tags: postgresql, query, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Bom eu tenho um projeto com scaffolds de livros e de emprestimos e preciso fazer uma busca de um livro especifico e como resultado mostrar todos os emprestimos em que aquele livro teve

não to fazendo ideia de como começar a fazer isso.

OBS: Estou começando a pouco tempo com ruby on rails e preciso muito disso, ja vi muitos artigos na internet mas que nao me ajudaram muito.

Bom Andersson Brantes, o codigo que vc colocou esta na logica que eu precisava, as video aulas tambem, so que eu não to conseguindo encaixar essa pesquisa no meu index que esta assim

```
def index
 @emprestimos = emprestimo.all.page(params[:page]).per(20)
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js { render json: @emprestimos, status: 200 }
   format.html
   format.json
   format.pdf {render template: 'emprestimos/report', pdf: 'report'}
 end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma tela com um formulário onde o usuário irá digitar o nome do livro,
 e, na mesma tela, logo abaixo, exibir os resultados da pesquisa(os emprestimos do livro pesquisado). Um exemplo para seguir seria:

Primeiro você precisa ter uma associação entre a model Livro e a model Emprestimo.

Na model Livro adicionar has_many

```
class Livro < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :emprestimos
end
```

E na model Emprestimos adicionar belongs_to

```
class Emprestimo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :livro
end
```

Obs: É preciso adicionar o campo livro_id na tabela emprestimos para a associação funcionar

Na controller de emprestimos, alterar o método index para:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    # Aqui e realizada a pesquisa do livro através do nome que foi digitado, para saber mais pesquise sobre "sql Like"
    @livro = Livro.where("nome like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%").take

    # Aqui é verificado se algum livro foi encontrado para buscar os empréstimos deste livro "@livro.emprestimos"
    @emprestimos = @livro ? @livro.emprestimos : []
  else
    # Quando nada foi pesquisado, todos os empréstimos serão exibidos
    @emprestimos = Emprestimo.all
  end    
end
```

E utilizar a view emprestimos/index.html.erb para adicionar o formulário de pesquisa no topo da página:

```
<%= form_tag(emprestimos_path, method: :get) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag 'search', nil, placeholder: 'Digite o nome do livro...' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Pesquisar' %>
<% end %>
```

Existem várias maneiras de fazer esta pesquisa, é só um simples exemplo para ter uma ideia de como começar.

Os exemplos que utilizei são baseados nos videos deste canal:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHPondVB9RQ&list=PLe3LRfCs4go-mkvHRMSXEOG-HDbzesyaP

Criando um formulário de pesquisa
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYcdrBAkR8s

Associações
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vh3ir1XWfW0